# What's the type of an entry of an unordered_map in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, unordered-map

I have a data struct:

```
unordered_map<pair<string, string>, unordered_map<pair<int, int>, double>> myMap;
```

I used a `for` loop to get its entry, and use this entry as an input of my function:

```
for (auto& map : myMap) { 
  auto myReturn = myFunc(map);
}
```

But when I am writing `myFunc`, I don't know what's the type of the parameter, is it a `pair`?

```
string myFunc(pair<pair<string, string>, unordered_map<pair<int, int>, double>> map)
```

Comment: There's a type alias for the value type if you need it. You can consult a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to see what it's aliased to.

Comment: This is why many software companies have code policies against the use of `auto` except in special situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over an `unordered_map` as shown in your example will yield [`unordered_map::value_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), which is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`. So in your case, the type of the variable `map` is

```
std::pair<const pair<string, string>, unordered_map<pair<int, int>, double>>
```

You're unable to call `myFunc` because the first element of the `pair` in `myFunc`'s parameter type must be `const` qualified.

Comment: So my guess was almost correct except I should make the key part `const`, right?

Comment: @EmersonXu Yes​. You should also think about creating a typedef or two instead writing that huge, unwieldy type name everywhere.